# PHP how do I count cells

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After a successful connection:

`mml` is my database, `tale` is my table

```
$sql = "Select * from `mml`.`tale`" ;
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);
    $records = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $field){
            echo "<td>".stripslashes($field)."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

As I'm populating all the fields, I would like to reference which field it's currently on: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.  I've tried count($field), but that just outputs itself, and count($row) outputs the total number.

Comment: You could do `foreach ($row as $cell => $field){` if you'd done `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM){`... though why are you still using the MySQL extension rather than MySQLi or PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you don't need the field names, so simply

```
$sql = "Select * from `mml`.`tale`" ;
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
$records = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $i => $field){
        echo "<td>".stripslashes($field)."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

`$i` will be the field index (0-based). If you need the field name, just change `MYSQL_NUM` to `MYSQL_ASSOC` and `$i` will be your field name.

PS: which PHP Version are you using?

> Warning
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_query()
> PDO::query()
> ```

Comment: say I wanted to call the second field in the row as a constant. like "<td>.striplashes($field)." - ".$field[1]."</td>, I wanted to use this technique to skip the first two fields, but still be abel to reference one of the fields constantly.  Thank you for the $row as $i => $field... I haven't used PHP in a while, and completely forgot about that.